# How to return the node ID in py2neo (Neo4J & Python)

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

Currently working with Py2neo to access my Neo4J database.

I have trouble with returning a node id. I already went through the documentation of Py2neo and read multiple StackOverflow posts but none of them contains a solid answer to my question. I think more people could use this solution.

I'm able to locate the node using NodeMatcher

```
from py2neo import Graph, NodeMatcher
from py2neo import Node, Relationship

graph = Graph("bolt://localhost:7687")
matcher = NodeMatcher(graph)

find_ingredient = matcher.match("Ingredient", name="Onion").first()
print(find_ingredient)
>>> (_6:Ingredient {name: 'Onion'})
```

How can I extract the Node ID (_6)?

The desired output would be

```
print(find_ingredient)
>>> 6
```

(_6 is also fine)

---

Second approach: I've added a property called 'ing_id'

```
ingredient = graph.run("MATCH (n:Ingredient {name:'Ui'}) WHERE n.name='Ui' RETURN n")
data = ingredient.data()
print(data)
>>>[{'n': Node('Ingredient', ing_id=1, name='Ui')}]
```

The desired output would be

```
print(ing_id)
>>> 1
```

What code do I need to add to achieve this?
Or is there an alternative (or better approach) to easily return the node id?

Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the problem. I hope this will help someone in the future.

```
#retreive the ingredient_id of the last added ingredient in the Neo4j db
  def last_ingredient_id():
     ingredient = graph.run("MATCH (a:Ingredient) RETURN a.ing_id ORDER BY a.ing_id DESC").to_series()
     result = int(ingredient[0])
     return result
```